# Understanding the quasiparticle lifetime

Tags: solid-state-physics

I have calculated the quasiparticle (QP) band structure in the GW approximation for an insulator and I'm trying to understand what the imaginary part of the self-energy represents. I understand how QP-QP scattering works in metals but in insulators, say near the bottom of the conduction band, the electron is not energetic enough to knock off a valence band electron. Is it then correct to say that if I have a filled valence band and one electron in the conduction band, then its lifetime is really infinite even though the calculation yields a nonzero imaginary self-energy? I would instead interpret the lifetime as representative of the scattering rate if there were more than electron in the conduction band, say under high excitation density.